# Ios Swift Animate a view in non linear path

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I am trying to animate a UIView through non linear path(i'm not trying to draw the path itself) like this :

[image: object animated through a curve]

The initial position of the view is determinated using a trailing and bottom constraint (`viewBottomConstraint.constant == 100` & `viewTrailingConstraint.constant == 300`)
I am using `UIView.animatedWithDuration` like this :

```
viewTrailingConstraint.constant = 20
viewBottomConstraint.constant = 450
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5,animation:{
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
},completition:nil)
```

But it animate the view in a linear path.

Comment: y dont u use core animation ?

Comment: To move an object along a path you should use a CAKeyFrame animation. Probably you will need to remove constraints before start and add them again at the end. https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/

Comment: good option but how can i create the path when i only know the start and the final position of the object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use keyFrame animation with path

```
    let keyFrameAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"position")
    let mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(mutablePath, nil,50,200)
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(mutablePath, nil,150,100, 250, 200)
    keyFrameAnimation.path = mutablePath
    keyFrameAnimation.duration = 2.0
    keyFrameAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    keyFrameAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
    self.label.layer.addAnimation(keyFrameAnimation, forKey: "animation")
```

Gif

[image]

About this function

```
void CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint (
   CGContextRef _Nullable c,
   CGFloat cpx,
   CGFloat cpy,
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y
);
```

`(cpx,cpy)` is control point,and `(x,y)` is end point
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Leo's answer of using Core Animation and `CAKeyframeAnimation` is good, but it operates on the view's "presentation layer" and only creates the appearance of moving the view to a new location. You'll need to add extra code to actually move the view to it's final location after the animation completes. Plus Core Animation is complex and confusing.

I'd recommend using the UIView method
`animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. You'd probably want to use the option value `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubic`, which causes the object to move along a curved path that passes through all of your points.

You call that on your view, and then in the animation block, you make multiple calls to `addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations:` that move your view to points along your curve.

I have a sample project on github that shows this and other techniques. It's called [**KeyframeViewAnimations**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations) (link)

### Edit:

(Note that UIView animations like `animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)` don't actually animate your views along the path you specify. They use a presentation layer just like CALayer animations do, and while the presentation layer makes the view look like it's moving along the specified path, it actually snaps from the beginning position to the end position at the beginning of the animation. UIView animations do move the view to its destination position, where CALayer animations move the presentation layer while not moving the layer/view at all.)

Another subtle difference between Leo's path-based UIView animation and my answer using UIView `animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)`is that CGPath curves are cubic or quadratic Bezier curves, and my answer animates using a different kind of curve called a Katmull-Rom spline. Bezier paths start and end at their beginning and ending points, and are attracted to, but don't pass through their middle control points. Catmull-Rom splines generate a curve that passes through every one of their control points.

Comment: The addition of `UIView.animateKeyframes` in the Swift 3 makes this answer the more appropriate solution.  Core Animation adds an unnecessary level of complexity for the original poster looking for basic animation of his UIView.

Comment: @ZacSketches, agreed, UIView.animateKeyframes is a simpler, high-level way to animate views, and much less complex to figure out. One point of order, though:  `animateKeyFrames` is an OS feature, not specific to Swift 3. It was added in iOS 7, if I remember correctly. I think that was before Swift was even available. So **every** version of Swift has allowed you to call `animateKeyFrames`